# Angular 2 update CKEditor textarea

Tags: angular

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/aUBtpe?p=preview

Using CKEditor, the `content` variable is not updated to the textarea value changes. It's stays the same as the orginal `page.content` variable received from the server.

the `console.log(content)` show the old data, without the changes I made to the textarea data.

Any ideas?

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: you are using `updater()` and `updateer()` do you have a typo?

Comment: Don't you think `ngModel` and `innerHTML` are conflicting?

Comment: @micronyks I want to get the value of my textarea. it actually don't. no typo it's just added after pasting

Comment: Post a plunkr reproducing the issue. And remove `[innerHTML]="page.content"` which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer It doesn't matter in this case. I tried with or without it, Whenever I change my textarea value the `console.log(content)` returns the same old data.

Comment: I still don't understand what do you want to do?

Comment: @micronyks I have textarea. I change the data inside my textarea. I want the new data, simply... **Im using CKEDITOR**! (code added in my question)

Comment: both links are different. Be clear @TheUnreal

Comment: Sorry had problem with the plunk links. This is is a demo plnuk: https://plnkr.co/edit/aUBtpe?p=preview

Comment: without ngOnInit I am able to run. But problem is with ngOnInit.

Comment: Yeah it is, the problem is the transofmration to the CKEditor. I am lookign for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple issues:

1. You need [ng2-ckeditor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-ckeditor) for ckeditor to work correctly with Angular2 framework.
2. Angular2(latest is 2.1.1) is released now, and beta.0 is really old. Current release of [ng2-ckeditor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-ckeditor) is base on Angular2 module import model, which was introduced in RC.5.
3. To have ng2-ckeditor working, BOTH

   In `index.html`

   `<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.11/full/ckeditor.js"></script>`

   AND `Module Import`

   ```
   import { CKEditorModule } from 'ng2-ckeditor';

   @NgModule({
     // ... 
     imports:      [
       CKEditorModule
     ],
     // ... 
   })
   ```

   are required.

I created a working [Plunker Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/fV4t6L?p=info).